# How to download the latest version (current: v2.2.5) files of JXLS?

Tags: jxls

the latest version in jXLS Web Site is v2.2.5
http://jxls.sourceforge.net/

the latest version in sourceforge is v2.2.4.
http://sourceforge.net/projects/jxls/

Where can I download v2.2.5?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you use Maven or similar?

Comment: thanks for your hint.
I had downloaded jar using maven.

Comment: Hi, you are welcome. I have written an answer for your problem, please accept it. To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from hollow to green.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I you manage your project's dependencies with Maven or another software project management tool you con simply add the proper dependency to your project.

If you use Maven you should add these lines to your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jxls</groupId>
    <artifactId>jxls</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Or you can go to [this URL](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jxls/jxls) to check if a more recent version exits.